# Internal laptop keyboard not working from live USB

Tags: keyboard, laptop

I got a new laptop (MSI Bravo 15 C7VFK Laptop) I can possibly install and use Linux (Artix Linux LXDE) for my new job, but before I go about switching over I want to make sure things work so if I have to I can still fallback on Windows.

I can boot into my USB and run it, using an external keyboard I can type. The touchpad works as well. But the internal keyboard does not seem to be working. It works from the boot menu where I select to run the OS and the BIOS. But from the live USB, it does not and I do not want to install it until I know the core things I need to work.

I did boot the Windows OS so I can get and update the BIOS, which I already did. I am not sure if there is a way to test this without installing the system.

I wonder if the linux-firmware package would fix this, but I would like to test without installing it.

Comment: does it work on the live images of less niche distros than Artix, like, say, the Ubuntu live image?

Comment: I actually had not thought of trying that, I will give it a shot and get back

Comment: So I tried it with Ubuntu as well, the same issue. The keyboard itself does not work

Comment: Thanks for trying, still! Now, booting whatever live medium you prefer, using an external keyboard, does `lsusb` list the keyboard as USB device?

Comment: I think so, `lsusb` shows a `Micro Star International MysticLight MS-1565` which Google comes up as the RGB light control, `lspci` does not seem to show anything related to a keyboard.

Comment: run `lsusb -v` and look for `bInterfaceClass` being "Human Interface Device" or `bInterfaceProtocol` being "Keyboard". I don't think your MysticLight thing is a keyboard,

Comment: (I'm really not versed in Windows, but if you can somehow figure out how the keyboard is internally connected and what driver Windows uses, that would probably be also helpful)

Comment: So that Micro Star does come up with bInterfaceClass of Human Interface Device, so it is the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Updating my kernel to linux64 on Manjaro fixed it for me and I've got a MSI Bravo 15 CV7E hope that this will help